# How can I determine whether it is safe to delete appdata folders in Windows

Tags: windows-7, temporary-files, ccleaner

I use CCleaner to clean the junk files in my computer.  I noticed that there are uninstalled applications still listed in the **Applications** section.

How can I automatically identify and delete these folders?

Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I normally just manually delete this files.

Comment: Yes, but where and how do I determine these files.

Comment: `AppData` is the location its a system variable specific to the current user.  You are in the best position to determine if your still using a product or not.  Of course if the program is uninstalled these often empty folders, and even if they have files in them, take virtually zero space because they contain files the application expects to be removed.

Comment: That pane lists applications that CCleaner thinks are installed.  You probably have some remnants left somewhere (eg. registry) on your system.  You can try using a product like [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) to ensure that all remaining application parts are gone.

Comment: @rrirower that's the problem. These applications were removed before I used Revo Uninstaller.